# Use variables defined in a different source file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, pointers

i want to get a value from another cpp file

for example this one is in fileone.cpp :

```
for (int i = 0; i < NSIZE(facerects); i++)
    {

        DetPar detpar;

        detpar.x = facerect->x + facerect->width / 2.;
        *gX=facerect->x;
        detpar.y = facerect->y + facerect->height / 2.;
        *gY=facerect->y;

    }
```

and i want to get the value of *gX , *gY in file2.cpp

in java we can do that with getters= but what is the easy way to do it in c++?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: i have *gX ,*gY in file1.cpp how can i get them in file2.cpp ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, would you like gX to be gY to be members of a class and access them? or you want them to be global, which I don't recommend

Comment: In Java, you use getters with a class.  C++ has classes too.  If you don't wanna use classes, create a header that both files include, which declares `gX` and `gY` as `extern`.

Comment: @DoesntMatter i want to access to the value of gX and gY from another cpp file ! how can i do that !!

Comment: @paddy could you give an examplel link !!

Comment: @tibou have done so as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If global variables are defined in another file, you can expose them using `extern`.
For example, if in file2.cpp you have variables declared as follows:

```
int *gX; // a pointer to an integer
int *gY;
```

Then in main.cpp you can use the variable using `extern`:

```
// define these near the top of your cpp file and then use them wherever you need to
extern int *gX; // a pointer to an integer defined elsewhere in your program
extern int *gY;
```

However, at least be careful to point to valid memory if you are going to use them the way you have in your source code. It would be better to simply use `int` (not pointers).

Also, it's worth considering the impact of using global variables [SO discussion of global variables in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872943/why-are-global-variables-bad-in-a-single-threaded-non-os-embedded-application)

Comment: i get this error error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int gX" (?gX@@3HA) . when i  used your method with int

Answer (score 1):

**fileone.h**

```
#ifndef FILEONE_H
#define FILEONE_H

extern int *gX;
extern int *gY;

#endif
```

**fileone.cpp**

```
#include "fileone.h"

// These are made available externally via fileone.h
int *gX = NULL;
int *gY = NULL;
```

**filetwo.cpp**

```
#include "fileone.h"

// gX and gY are available, but are defined in fileone.cpp
```

Comment: However, generally speaking, avoid extern variables at all cost. Otherwise, the organization/architecture of your code will be a mess.

Comment: I don't agree with sweeping generalisations like that, @DoesntMatter.  If used tastefully, this sort of thing is just fine, and quite normal.  For this particular case I don't think extern variables are appropriate though =)

Comment: i get this error error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int gX" (?gX@@3HA)

Comment: That means you either haven't defined it globally in `fileone.cpp` as I showed, or you didn't link properly.  Are both the cpp files part of the same project?