# Reverse a string using Cstrings in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, c-strings

I'm trying to take a users input and reverse it for comparison later. Looks like I'm going in the right direction, but I can't seem to figure out why my method only returns one letter. It should return the entire Cstring reversed when I cout reversedInput.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void reverseString(char arr[100]);
char reversedInput[100];


int main() {

    char input[100];


    cout<<"Please enter a string"<<endl;
    cin.getline(input, 100);
    cout<<"You entered "<<input<<endl;

    reverseString(input);
    cout<<"The reverse is "<<reversedInput<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void reverseString (char arr[]) {
    int i;
    int j = strlen(arr) - 1;
    char temp;

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++, j--) {
        temp = arr[j];
        //        arr[j];
        reversedInput[i] = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: You never added the null terminator for reversedInput.

Comment: @drescherjm the OP doesn't have to. The target buffer is global, and used only once. It is zero filled, so the terminator (while expensive) is free. Not a great design, but it will work none-the-less.

Comment: Why not just use `std::string`?  It has `crbegin()` and `crend()` that give you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is `i < j` in your conditional. As you descend the source string, `j` decrements while `i` increments, eventually meeting halfway up the string, and leaving you with half not being copied.

```
void reverseString(const char arr[]) 
{
    size_t len = strlen(arr);
    for (size_t i = 0; len-- > 0; ++i)
        reversedInput[i] = arr[len];
}
```

Note, the avoidance of computing `strlen(arr)-1` is intentional. Consider what that becomes when/if you pass an *empty* string to this function. (Hint: unsigned types legally underflow to their extreme maximum).

That said, there's plenty potentially worrisome here, particularly the potential to overreach the size of `reversedInput`, relying on it being static (thus zero-filled so a free terminator), and the side-effects of modifying a global in the first place (should be an output argument). But the core problem was one of the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store contents of array `arr` in reverse way in global array `reversedInput` then one way is this, though [Why Global Variables Should Be Avoided When Unnecessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872943/why-are-global-variables-bad-in-a-single-threaded-non-os-embedded-application)

```
void reverseString (char arr[]) {
        for (size_t i = 0, j = strlen(arr); j-- > 0 ; i++) { /* change the condition from i<j to j>=0*/
                reversedInput[i] = arr[j]; /* filling in global array in reverse order */
        }
        reversedInput[i] = '\0'; /* terminate with \0 */
}
```

Comment: why not use `std::swap`?

Comment: True @BradAllred that's even better.

Comment: Maybe they don’t want to modify the original array? This wouldn’t work then

Comment: yes true @TobySpeight you are right. I don't tested as I was answering using mobile application. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose Input string is "nitendra" and you want o reverse it. You can reverse a string just swapping first character with last character , then second character with second last character and so on.. till (length of string)/2.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    void reverseString(char arr[100]);
    char reversedInput[100];


    int main() {

        char input[100];


        cout<<"Please enter a string"<<endl;
        cin.getline(input, 100);
        cout<<"You entered "<<input<<endl;

        reverseString(input);
        cout<<"The reverse is "<<input<<endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    void reverseString (char* arr)
    {
        size_t len = std::strlen(arr);

        for(size_t i=0;i<(size_t)(len/2);++i)
        {
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[len-i-1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.